# How to parse url in spark sql(Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using following function to parse url but it throws error,

```
val b = Seq(("http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1"),("https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/#negative")).toDF("url_col")
        .withColumn("host",parse_url($"url_col","HOST"))
        .withColumn("query",parse_url($"url_col","QUERY"))
        .show(false)
```

Error:

```
<console>:285: error: not found: value parse_url
               .withColumn("host",parse_url($"url_col","HOST"))
                                  ^
<console>:286: error: not found: value parse_url
               .withColumn("query",parse_url($"url_col","QUERY"))
                                   ^
```

Kindly Guide how to parse url into its different parts.

Comment: parse_url is your custom function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer by @Ramesh is correct, but you also might want some hacky way to use this function without SQL queries :)

Hack is in the fact, that "callUDF" function calls not only UDFs, but any available function.

So you can write:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

b.withColumn("host", callUDF("parse_url", $"url_col", lit("HOST"))).
 withColumn("query", callUDF("parse_url", $"url_col", lit("QUERY"))).
 show(false)
```

Edit: after [this Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22249) is merged, you can just use `parse_url` like a normal function. PR made after this question :)

Answer (score 5):

**`parse_url` is available as only sql and not as api** . refer to [parse_url](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#parse_url)

so you *should be using it as a sql query and not as a function call through api*

You should *register the dataframe* and *use query* as below

```
val b = Seq(("http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1"),("https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/#negative")).toDF("url_col")

b.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
spark.sql("SELECT url_col, parse_url(`url_col`, 'HOST') as HOST, parse_url(`url_col`,'QUERY') as QUERY from temp").show(false)
```

which should give you output as

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------+
|url_col                                                                                     |HOST             |QUERY  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------+
|http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1                                                        |spark.apache.org |query=1|
|https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/#negative|people.apache.org|null   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned before, when you register a UDF you don't get a Java function, rather you introduce it to Spark, so you must call it in the "Spark-way".

I want to suggest another method I find convenient, especially when there are several columns you want to add, by using `selectExpr`

```
val b = Seq(("http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1"),("https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/#negative")).toDF("url_col")
val c = b.selectExpr("*", "parse_url(url_col, 'HOST') as host", "parse_url(url_col, 'QUERY') as query")
c.show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a library called [bebe](https://github.com/MrPowers/bebe) that exposes the `parse_url` functionality via the Scala API.

Suppose you have the following DataFrame:

```
+------------------------------------+---------------+
|some_string                         |part_to_extract|
+------------------------------------+---------------+
|http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1|HOST           |
|http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1|QUERY          |
|null                                |null           |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Calculate the different parts of the URL:

```scala
df.withColumn("actual", bebe_parse_url(col("some_string"), col("part_to_extract")))
```

```
+------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|some_string                         |part_to_extract|actual          |
+------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1|HOST           |spark.apache.org|
|http://spark.apache.org/path?query=1|QUERY          |query=1         |
|null                                |null           |null            |
+------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
```